# xcode 5 app crashes on ios simulator (7.1) after loading launch image

Tags: xcode5, ios7.1, crash

if I'll open my app in the iOS Simulator (iPhone 4" iOS 7.1 64-bit) the app crashes after loading the launch image.

In the Log Output is ,,(lldb)" written. Maybe it helps someone.

Hope anyone could help me.
Greatings from Germany!

Comment: Error?  Stacktrace? Log? Screenshots? Give us *details* for your current problem and someone may help you:)

Comment: The only thing you show here is one exception hierarchy.Nobody can help you from this screenshot.

Comment: ok, I'm new in developing iOS Apps. What screenshot do I have to post?

Comment: First check this tutorial http://codewithchris.com/xcode-tutorial/    And in debug area show console output,there probably will have some stacktrace after application launch.

Comment: Ok, in the Output is this ,,(lldb)". Hope it's helpful